# Sort shapes in a slide (pptx) top>bottom, left>right but with a threshold

Tags: python, list, sorting, powerpoint, python-pptx

Based on previous questions I have the following code:

```
def iter_textable_shapes(shapes):
    for shape in shapes:
        if shape.has_text_frame:
            yield shape


def iter_textframed_shapes(shapes):
    """Generate shape objects in *shapes* that can contain text.

    Shape objects are generated in document order (z-order), bottom to top.
    """
    for shape in shapes:
        # ---recurse on group shapes---
        if shape.shape_type == pptx.enum.shapes.MSO_SHAPE_TYPE.GROUP:
            group_shape = shape
            for shape in iter_textable_shapes(group_shape.shapes):
                yield shape
            continue

        # ---otherwise, treat shape as a "leaf" shape---
        if shape.has_text_frame:
            yield shape



textable_shapes = list(iter_textframed_shapes(slide.shapes))
ordered_textable_shapes = sorted(
            textable_shapes, key=lambda shape: (shape.top, shape.left)
)
```

It works good on most of the cases. However, sometimes this behaviour is too simple, for example:
[image]

the description "aaaaaa..." ends up before title because effectively the text starts upper than the title. I'd like to apply a sort of threshold in order to have this behaviour: if shape a is upper than shape b of more than threshold t, then in the order a is first; instead if the difference is under t and b is on the left wrt a, then b is first in the order.
How can I do so?

I tried this line but doesn't seem to work

```
sorted(shapes, key=lambda shape: (shape.top, shape.left) if shape.height > threshold else (shape.left, shape.top))
```

Comment: Should the sort really be that simple?